# Assign output from AWS CLI command to 2nd AWS CLI command

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am writing automation task for creating AWS AMI image, the goal is get output from `aws import-image` (.ova to ami convert) and add the name in 2nd command:

```
importaskid=$(aws ec2 import-image --disk-containers  Format=ova,UserBucket="{S3Bucket=acp17,S3Key=XXXXX.ova}" | jq -r '.ImportTaskId')

aws ec2 create-tags --resources echo $importaskid --tags 'Key=Name, Value=acp_ami_test'
```

I am able to `$importaskid` and see needed output but when use `aws ec2 create-tags` the AMI image created without name and the output from 2nd command is empty.

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide the contents of `importaskid`, the (wrong) `aws ec2 create-tags` command generated by your script and the (correct) expected `aws ec2 create-tags` command you're trying to generate

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
# set bash variable "importaskid":
importaskid=$(aws ec2 import-image --disk-containers Format=ova,UserBucket="{S3Bucket=acp17,S3Key=XXXXX.ova}" | jq -r '.ImportTaskId')

# Verify that importaskid is set correctly
echo $importaskid

# Now use it:
aws ec2 create-tags --resources "$importaskid" --tags 'Key=Name, Value=acp_ami_test'
```

The "$()" syntax for assigning the output of a command to a variable is discussed here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/

The double quotes in `"$importaskid"` would be necessary if the value of "$importaskid" happens to have spaces in it.

Comment: Thanks for reply but still the same , AMI image create but without name and i got empty output when running the 2nd command

Comment: Q: "I  got empty output when running the 2nd command".  A: Then probably the command isn't doing what think.  Q: Do you get output when you execute the SAME command directly from the CLI, without "$importaskid = $(...)"?  Q: Are you sure your aws command syntax is OK? Typing the command directly from the CLI will give you an error message if it isn't. Q: Are you sure your shell is "bash" (which supports "$(...)" syntax), vs. some other shell (e.g. "sh", which requires `...` back-ticks instead)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply,

Comment: A gentle reminder: it looks like you've been with SO for 5 years ... but haven't "accepted" (or even "upvoted?) single reply or posted a single "resolution" to any of your questions yet :(

Comment: Hi, the issue solved by adding this solution( by assign name to ami-image and not to import task id (technically impossible for that)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply, so when i run the command without echo $ImportTaskId
see below

`aws ec2 create-tags --resource import-ami-XXXXXXXXXXXXX --tags Key=Name,Value='name_ami_test'`

i got empty response and the name is not assigned in aws console so i will speak to AWS support/check syntax /check after the assign name to AMI ID and not to import-ami-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX